# Apriori Algorithm - not getting the rules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, apriori

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVv9Z.png)

Here is my code and I have given an image of my dataset "Market_Basket_Optimisation". I have made list of lists transaction to give the input in apriori algorithm.But I am not getting the rules. I am new to machine learning and I am not able to find out the error.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Data Preprocessing
dataset = pd.read_csv('Market_Basket_Optimisation.csv', header = None)
transactions = []
for i in range(0, 7501):
    transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 20)])

# Training Apriori on the dataset
from apyori import apriori
rules = apriori(transactions, min_support = 0.003, min_confidence = 0.2, min_lift = 3, min_length = 2)

# Visualising the results
results = list(rules)
```

Comment: try to provide the table as a text , instead of as image

Comment: It exceeds the word limit. I have tried it giving in form of image

Comment: This is the link for dataset:https://www.superdatascience.com/pages/machine-learning

Comment: The file name is Market_Basket_Optimisation.csv under section Section 28:Apriori in Apriori-Python-zip file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you are using jupyter notebook or an IDE such as Spyder. If you are using an IDE such as Spyder, you are not likely to see the result unless you use a print statement. I suggest adding another line as follows:
print(resuult)
You should see the rules list. This is the same issue I had and using the print statement solved the problem for me. You will still need to define a function to output the result in a tabular format that makes sense.